# Magento 2 - Email Template insert variable in html format

Tags: magento2

I have create `QR_Code` on `sales_orde`r table and append   {{var order.qr_code }}
on template and only display as string on the email content 
 translate into text form
example

```
< to &lt
> to &gt;
```

I try  `{{var order.qr_code|raw}}` but didn't work. As i want show QR code on new order new email.

Answer (score 9):

To display in email qr_code from sales_order table you should write

```
{{var order.getQrCode()|raw}}
```

Comment: Than you Its working for me